# KeyCloak and Quarkus can't start in dev mode

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

Hello I am currently trying to do this tutorial : https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-authorization

But when I run `quarkus dev` I get this error.

```
ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148)
    at io.quarkus.keycloak.pep.runtime.KeycloakPolicyEnforcerRecorder.createPolicyEnforcer(KeycloakPolicyEnforcerRecorder.java:65)
    at io.quarkus.keycloak.pep.runtime.KeycloakPolicyEnforcerRecorder.setup(KeycloakPolicyEnforcerRecorder.java:37)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.KeycloakPolicyEnforcerBuildStep$setup1036344509.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.KeycloakPolicyEnforcerBuildStep$setup1036344509.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:103)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

I did everything as intended in the tutorial

until starting the Quarkus project in dev mode.

Comment: could you try without the ```%prod``` prefix in ```%prod.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://localhost:8543/realms/quarkus``` in application.properties. and you need to configure it for your Keycloak auth server URL too.